# How can I automatically save a photo when a Facebook Page posts a photo?

Tags: automation, dropbox, google-drive, facebook, api

My brother is in a band and his band's page posts photos of the gigs. I want to save all these photos automatically since I love my brother and want to catalog all his gigs. Any way I can automatically detect when his band's Facebook Page posts a photo, and then download the full-size render of it to somewhere safe like my Dropbox or Google Drive?

I looked through IFTTT, but it's clear you need to be the page owner to do anything remotely close to that so I think I'm looking for an IFTTT-like service that provides this option for non-Page-owners, or a homebrew solution using Facebook's API.

I'm running Mac OS X and don't mind having some kind of scripted solution that runs in the background on my machine and gets the job done. Doesn't have to be an external service, though that'd be ideal so we don't have to reinvent the wheel. Not looking for you to write the entire program if that's what it comes to, but a framework would be nice. Ideally, a third-party service would be best.

Anyone got the 411?

Comment: I'm running Mac OS X and don't mind having some kind of scripted solution that runs in the background on my machine and gets the job done. Doesn't have to be an external service, though that'd be ideal so we don't have to reinvent the wheel. Not looking for you to write the entire program if that's what it comes to, but a framework would be nice. Ideally, a third-party service would be best.

Comment: Do not add necessary or relevant information as a comment. Instead, EDIT your question in order to include this in the original post.